# Retagging [firefox] [mozilla] questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Almost all of the questions tagged with [mozilla](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) are questions about Firefox or Thunderbird, for example:

- [Is there a Firefox extension to bookmark a specific position on a webpage?](https://superuser.com/questions/264338/is-there-a-firefox-extension-to-bookmark-a-specific-position-on-a-webpage)
- [How to override the CSS of a site in Firefox with userContent.css?](https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-to-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css)

I don't think Firefox-related questions should include the [mozilla](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) tag, because from reading the tag description it seems to me that it should be used for general questions about the Mozilla foundation or Mozilla products in general:

> Mozilla is a suite of Internet free and multiplatform applications
>   whose components include a browser, an email client, an HTML editor
>   and an IRC chat client.

Should I go over questions like these and retag them? Maybe we should add `"Do not use for product-specific questions such as Firefox or Thunderbird"` in the tag description?

There are some questions that should be tagged with [mozilla](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mozilla), like these two:

- [Can I change the language of a Mozilla product without reinstalling?](https://superuser.com/questions/163949/can-i-change-the-language-of-a-mozilla-product-without-reinstalling)
- [Why does Internet Explorer identify itself as Mozilla?](https://superuser.com/questions/113020/why-does-internet-explorer-calls-itself-mozilla)

So I can see why this tag can be useful.

---

After going over all the [mozilla](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) questions (thoroughly), these are the only questions the seem to fit the [mozilla](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) tag:

- [Why does Internet Explorer identify itself as Mozilla?](https://superuser.com/questions/113020/why-does-internet-explorer-calls-itself-mozilla)
- [Can I change the language of a Mozilla product without reinstalling?](https://superuser.com/questions/163949/can-i-change-the-language-of-a-mozilla-product-without-reinstalling)
- https://superuser.com/questions/392582/where-did-mozilla-placed-the-xpi-for-locale-language
- [How does adding a device in Firefox Sync work, when Mozilla never knows your encryption key?](https://superuser.com/questions/336355/how-does-adding-a-device-in-firefox-sync-work-when-mozilla-never-knows-your-enc)
- [Mozilla Sync (wsgi via apache) through SSL causes error 500, no log entries](https://superuser.com/questions/405820/mozilla-sync-wsgi-via-apache-through-ssl-causes-error-500-no-log-entries)

Comment: How many questions are purely about the Mozilla suite? If it's just a few, we'd be better off removing the Mozilla tag, moving everything to Firefox, and then re-creating it for those few left.

Comment: About 10 (out of 105). I searched for [mozilla]mozilla and most of the questions relate to a Mozilla product ([like here](http://superuser.com/questions/387363/mozilla-10-add-on-compatible) - "Mozilla 10").

Comment: If it's just 10, it's easier to make a list of those for later and then just move everything "Mozilla" to Firefox indeed, then retag those ten. Would it be possible for you to include links to those in your question?

Comment: @slhck I added links to those questions.

Comment: @slhck I found out it's the same case with `[google-chrome][google]`. Should I open a new question, or edit this one? I'll add links to the questions that fit the [google] tag as well.

Comment: Let's do one at a time, I guess. Easier to handle that way :) I'll do the mass-retagging for Mozilla later or tomorrow and notify you when done.

Comment: @slhck No problem. I really appreciate your help here on meta SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this is done.

I've remapped everything from [mozilla](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) to [firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox) and recreated the Mozilla tag, along with a tag wiki, which now mentions that this tag is not about Firefox or Thunderbird.

I've also removed any reference of [firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox) from [thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird) questions where it was mapped from Mozilla before.

Comment: Great. **1)** Can you also add `[mozilla-firefox]` as a synonym for `[firefox]`, so people that refer to Firefox as "Mozilla" or "Mozilla Firefox" will see the Firefox tag suggestion when typing "Mozilla"? **2)** Do you want me to open a new question regarding Chrome questions tagged with `[google]`, or should I edit this question?

Comment: 1) Done 2) I'd post a separate question. Meta traffic is so low it'll be easier to see that way.

Comment: I just checked and there are 3 new questions tagged with the `[mozilla]` tag, even though they shouldn't be - they only relate to Firefox. Besides retagging them manually, do you think we can do something to prevent this?

Comment: @tempy How do I put this … you can't prevent users from ignoring the tag descriptions. There's really nothing we can do other than going over this again and again and again. That, or we sacrifice the Mozilla tag and make it a synonym with Firefox.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to do that. Same for the `[google]` and `[microsoft]` tags (and probably others) that don't really have a purpose, since on SuperUser you don't ask questions about the company but about its products.