# Retagging [microsoft] questions

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Same as the 2 previous questions I've posted:

- [Retagging [google] questions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5871/retagging-google-questions)
- [Retagging [firefox] [mozilla] questions?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5853/retagging-firefox-mozilla-questions)

Most of the questions tagged with [microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) (180 questions) relate to Microsoft products (mostly Windows and Office) and they are not questions about Microsoft corporation or Microsoft products in general, and that's why I don't think they should be tagged with [microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft).

**Microsoft tag wiki:**

> Microsoft is a software company best known for
>   their Windows line of operating systems.

Comment: That (meta) tag has to be removed entirely, it really has no meaning. Just like "Apple".

Comment: [Related topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3948/company-tag-necromancy-the-zombie-apocalypse).

Comment: @DanielBeck I think we can easily get rid of `[microsoft]`, `[google]` and `[mozilla]` and all the ones [you mentioned](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5648/165729) in the 'useless' category.